# Android : How to Run method in service on different thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I trying to do some long time operation in service which is started from the controller.

```
public void startDashboardBgService() {
        Boolean isAppInForeground = Container.getInstance().isAppInForeground();
        if (isAppInForeground) {
            stopDashboardBgService();
            context.startService(new Intent(context, DashboardService.class));
        }
    }
```

Then i calling long time operation method from the onStartCommand event.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Logger.d("onStartCommand");
        updateDashboardValues();
        handler =  new Handler();
        context = this;
        return mStartMode;
    }
```

And here is the method which should to do work on the separated thread.

```
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<Reminder> reminders = Reminder.getAllRemindersFromDB(context);
        if (reminders.size() > 0) {
            for (Reminder r : reminders) {
                Logger.d(r.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            Logger.d("No reminders in table, dashboard cannot be updated");
        }
    }
};

private void updateDashboardValues() {
    try {
        Thread t = new Thread(runnableCode);
        t.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TrackingEventLogHelper.logException(e, Constants.Global.EXCEPTION,
                Constants.ExceptionMessage.EXC_CANNOT_CANCEL_UNIQUE_ALARM_FOR_DASHBOARD_CHECK, true);
    }
}
```

But when is the method called from activity (controller) UI is lagging and i getting following message.

```
Skipped 604 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

How can i solve it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: have you tried running the code in an `AsyncTask`? This is (in most cases) the preferred solution over using a `Thread` by yourself

Comment: Yes, but i was not able to make it work in service. Could You please add some example usage for method in the service service. ?

Comment: Regular Service run on the main thread. If you want to do background work in a Service, you can use the IntentService implementation instead.

Comment: But usage AsyncTask in service is good solution too, or not?

Comment: @redrom I posted a basic usage example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the code inside an `AsyncTask`, see an example below. Note: you can parameterize it with any types you need.

**Edit**: example of how to pass parameters (`Context` in this case) to the task.

```
 new AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>() {

        //local fields

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //runs on UI Thread
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
           /* runs on UI Thread instead of onPostExecute()
               if cancel(boolean) was called */
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
            //runs on UI Thread
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {
          //background Thread - do heavy work here
            Context c = params[0];
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          //runs on UI Thread
        }

    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new **Thread & a Runnable** and wrap your method in it.

Or you can use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which takes care of running your methods in a worker thread automatically

Answer (score 1):

Android Services by default, run on UI thread. If you have to do some heavy work you need to perform it on worker thread.

It would be better to use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for long running operations, because using AsyncTask for long running operations is not recommended.